# Allow viewing of CHM files through an application on a shared folder

Tags: windows, powershell, chm

Our users want the see CHM help docs through the application by clicking on the help icon (question mark in the application menu). Application is MiniTab. MiniTab application is usually a per workstation install but we want to run the app through network share. When we try to view help through the application, I get a standard Windows Help dialogue but the content is blank.

Implementing all of the plethora of registry information from Microsoft with KB 892675 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892675, I successfully double-click to view the CHM file on a UNC file share if I set Registry Key ItssRestrictions and value MaxAllowedZone to 2.

Good PowerShell code to view CHM files on shared folder:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x"
$name = "ItssRestrictions"
# New Reg Key
New-Item -Path $registryPath -Name $name
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions"
$name = "MaxAllowedZone"
$value = 2
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -Force
# Verify your changes
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x"
```

Furthermore, following the MS KB, I tried allowing nested protocol and white listing the CHM UNC, 'file://' prefix and also mapped drive format. Nothing works.

After trying to view the Help file through the application, event viewer has a message:
"The description for Event ID 1 from source ITSS cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repaired the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

\UNCPathToTheCHMFolder\Mtb.chm
"

Sorry if I didn't use the right terminology for Registry. I'm still learning the magic of Windows Registry.

My gut feeling is an undocumented MS restriction on applications from opening CHM files. Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Please avoid recommending the standard practice of installing or copying the app locally to the workstation. We have monitored the local install and set the appropriate registry settings for the application. Thanks but I know the CHM files will work if I copy the app locally to the workstation and we're beyond local installs at this point.

Comment: Difficult to answer because of many possible IT environments (e.g. developer, administrator and customer). Excuse me, but making sure you don't struggle about following issue: Do you have a pound sign (hash #) in the path or CHM filename?

Comment: @help-info.de , No, no # in the path to CHM file. I'm guessing a # could be used as a bookmark to jump to a section, but there's nothing like that here. Simply want to open the CHM file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have searched for a while by Google. Because of many environments please go deeper into following links I listed below. Please comment which one you know already.

HelpwareGroup knowledge base:
[Security Updates Break HH](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/security-updates-break-hh)

Peter Grainge's Info:
[CHM Files Not Working](http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/chm_mspatch/896358.htm)

MGTEK Help Producer:
[CHM help files on network shares do not display correctly](https://www.mgtek.com/helpproducer/manual/html/msprbChmOnUNC.html)

Notes by Tom:
[HTML Help CHM File in Shared Folder](https://notesbytom.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/html-help-chm-file-in-shared-folder/)

> Please note: Make sure to put the same URL’s in both the 32 and 64-bit UrlAllowList registry locations. You MUST include each UNC path twice, once beginning with “\” and a second time beginning with “file://\” to cover different scenarios under which the help content may be accessed.

HHReg Help & Manual:
[CHM files on network drives](http://www.helpandmanual.com/products_hhreg.html)

Comment: Good point on 64 and 32 registry. These are 64 bit Windows so good idea adding to both parts of the reg.