# C# Help.ShowHelp White Right Panel network .chm

Tags: c#, wpf, chm, html-help

I am trying to start my help from my C# wpf application and so I use :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, @"//UNCPATH/Help.chm", System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator.Topic, "/GOOD_TOPIC.htm");
```

And this starts the hh.exe with the help but the right panel is completely white like if it couldn't render it.

I also tried the

```
Process.Start("hh.exe", "//UNCPATH/Help.chm")
```

and this gives the same result.

But When I use a local path Help.ShowHelp works and when I use the Windows run window with:`hh.exe //UNCPATH/Help.chm`  it works.

I don't think UNC path is the problem here because even with a mapped drive I have the same result. My best guest is thew network drive is the problem here but then again I don't have the problem when I use something out of my code.

Could this be a `32/64 bit` problem (my app is compiled as `32-bit` on a `64-bit` Windows 7 OS)

**EDIT :**

After some more research when compiled in `x64` it works on my pc but not when compiled in `x86`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39859155/62576

Comment: I get that, first problem is that I am not admin on my PC and can't modify does register, and what is really strange to me is that I can run it manually but not from my code, why is that?

Comment: Using a mapped drive should solve the problem no?

Comment: Did you review the links in the answer to that question? There are many of them; one of them should answer your question. But mapping a drive letter to a shared drive does not magically make it no longer a shared drive.